# Trouble converting a curl command to a request-promise command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl

So I know that this curl command does work. When I run it, I get the html document that should appear after this login:

```
curl 'https://login.url' 
-H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
-H 'Origin: https://blah' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' 
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
-H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 
-H 'Referer: https://blash.jsp' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data 'Username=mary&Password=<PASSWORD>&Go=Login&Action=Srh-1-1' --compressed ;
```

This is my attempt at converting it to a node request promise. When I run it, I get some weird characters back.

```
var url = 'https://login.url';

var headers = {
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Origin': 'https://blah',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Referer': 'https://blash.jsp',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

var data = {
  'Username':'mary',
  'Password':'<Password>',
  'Go':'Login',
  'Action':'Srh-1-1'
}

var html = yield request.post({url:url,form:data,headers:headers});
```

Here's an example of the weird characters:

```
�X}o�6����4\��b�N��%
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `request` that you accept compression by setting the `gzip` option to true.

Be aware that depending on how/where you get the data, you may get the compressed or uncompressed response. Check the [documentation for `request`](https://github.com/request/request) for details (search for "compr" on the page).